# How can we know if there are any new vulnerabilities to open source software automatically?

Tags: python, security, open-source, auto-update, rss-reader

I have a tool which uses around 50+ opensource softwares, if any of those opensource softwares got exploited and a new vulnerability raised, I need be notified immediately and i should patch that respective software.

So, is there any way to do that?

I have searched few things like CVE reports, opensource threat intelligence platforms, but i failed to find the way to it.

Answer (score 0):

Great, great question! Many people aren't aware of this problem, it's huge when you think about the implications, as you have.

The truth is, it's quite difficult to do so. In some tools, such as Node Package Manager (NPM), you can use `npm audit` to check against a security database. This will then produce a report of the vulnerabilities in the list of repositories (most of which are generally open source) and explain their vulnerability status.

However, a great tool that solves this problem is called [Synk](https://snyk.io). Check it out. It's essentially npm audit on steroids, with great customer support (I don't work for them, so not trying to sell here).

**What to do**

You can integrate either `npm audit` or Snyk into your pipeline (best in CI if you have this setup). Then upon every deployment, you can ensure that the repositories have at least been checked for vulnerabilities.